# how to handle RDD without iterations in pyspark

Tags: lambda, pyspark, set, rdd

I have an RDD that I read from a file with the current format

199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
...

I got the fields that I need with this piece of code:

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x : (x.split(" ")[0], x.split(" ")[3][1:12], x.split(" ")[5], x.split(" ")[7], x.split(" ")[8]))
```

and now on this add, I got this setup

```
    rdd.take(4)
[('199.72.81.55', '01/Jul/1995', '"GET', 'HTTP/1.0"', '200'), ('unicomp6.unicomp.net', '01/Jul/1995', '"GET', 'HTTP/1.0"', '200'), ('199.120.110.21', '01/Jul/1995', '"GET', 'HTTP/1.0"', '200'),('199.120.110.21', '01/Jul/1995', '"GET', 'HTTP/1.0"', '200')]
```

I need the unique hosts on this file, so I did this:

```
    rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x : x[0])
```

and I got this:

```
    rdd2(take(4))
    ['199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21', '199.120.110.21']
```

so far, so good
but now I have a trouble that I can't understand

```
    h = set()
    rdd2.map(lambda x: h.add(x))  #line with error, i suppose
    print(h)
    {} # the set is empty, i have no idea why my set isn't adding the values to the set
```

what I expect is a set with unique values like this:

```
{'199.72.81.55', 'unicomp6.unicomp.net', '199.120.110.21'}
```

can anyone point to me why the lambda to add the value to the set it's not working